# Skew in mysql memory usage compared to configured values

Tags: mysql, linux, database

MySQL v8.0.23, InnoDB engine

I have configured innodb buffer pool size =80GB, and max threads used are 423. However, there is significant difference in memory consumed by mysql vs expected max value of RAM usage. What could be the contributing factors for the extra 17GB?

```
    SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + 423 * (@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size + @@join_buffer_size + @@tmp_table_size )) / (1024*1024*1024)
AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;
+---------------+
| MAX_MEMORY_GB |
+---------------+
| 86.5277 |
+---------------+
```

As per above, max usage of memory ~87GB. However, top and free show following:

```
free -mh
total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem: 119G 104G 876M 908K 14G 13G
Swap: 0B 0B 0B 

top -o %MEM
PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
26502 mysql 20 0 0.103t 0.102t 12120 S 113.3 86.7 265894:41 mysqld
129344 root 19 -1 352404 138448 133868 S 0.0 0.1 9:12.45 systemd-journal
```

Output of pt-mysql-summary

```
# InnoDB #####################################################
Version | 8.0.23
Buffer Pool Size | 80.0G
Buffer Pool Fill | 90%
Buffer Pool Dirty | 0%
File Per Table | ON
Page Size | 16k
Log File Size | 2 * 512.0M = 1.0G
Log Buffer Size | 32M
Flush Method | fsync
Flush Log At Commit | 0
XA Support |
Checksums |
Doublewrite | ON
R/W I/O Threads | 32 32
I/O Capacity | 200
Thread Concurrency | 0
Concurrency Tickets | 5000
Commit Concurrency | 0
Txn Isolation Level |
Adaptive Flushing | ON
Adaptive Checkpoint |
Checkpoint Age | 3M
InnoDB Queue | 0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
Oldest Transaction | 0 Seconds
History List Len | 36
Read Views | 0
Undo Log Entries | 1 transactions, 2 total undo, 2 max undo
Pending I/O Reads | 0 buf pool reads, 0 normal AIO, 0 ibuf AIO, 0 preads
Pending I/O Writes | 0 buf pool (0 LRU, 0 flush list, 0 page); 0 AIO, 0 sync, 0 log IO (0 log, 0 chkp); 0 pwrites
Pending I/O Flushes | 478553 buf pool, 0 log
Transaction States | 1xACTIVE (PREPARED), 4xnot started
```

Comment: Post TEXT results from OS Command Prompt, A) HTOP  B) TOP   you likely have more processes running in addition to your MySQL/MariaDB primary activity.

Comment: No other processes. As you can see, I have shared output of top which is sorted by memory usage (desc). There was no other process. I monitored it for several minutes

Comment: Please post complete TEXT Results of  
A) top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
B) top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a critical ( and ) in your query, the following may be more accurate for you.

```
SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + ( 423 * (@@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size + @@join_buffer_size + @@tmp_table_size ))) / (1024*1024*1024)
```

AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;